# add prop types to render props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-proptypes

When using regular react components, there are multiple ways to enable intellisense for a component (through prop types for functional componentds, or jsdoc comments), but if the component uses the render prop pattern like this:

```js
return this.props.children({ config, onClickConfig })
```

and used like this:

```js
<ConsumerComponent>
  {
    ({config, onClickConfig}) => (<button type="button" onClick={onClickConfig}>{config}</button>)
  }
</ConsumerComponent>
```

is there any way that we can enable intellisense for the type of the `config` object or the `onClickConfig` function ?

I see that typescript can enable this, by reusing the types in the consumer, but is it possible to achieve using jsdocs or prop types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be to use both and document well.

```
const propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // ... other proptypes
}

/**
 * @param {object} props the props object
 * @param {({ config: React.ElementType, onClickConfig: function }) => React.ElementType} props.children the render prop
 */
const ConsumerComponent = ({ children, ...props }) => ( ..... );
ConsumerComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
```

Comment: This was helpful. I was able to take inspiration from this and expose the arguments of the function to the consumer

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Unfortunately, `PropTypes` doesn't allow type checking a function's (render prop) arguments during runtime. If you're using Typescript, then an invalid argument type should prevent compilation during buildtime (provided [noEmitOnError](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError) is set to true). However, since you're trying to type during runtime, then you'll have to do it with your own custom validator function.

### Solution

[image: Edit Type Checking Render Prop]

Clicking on the `Open Modal` button throws an error. To correct the error, change [Line 72](https://codesandbox.io/s/type-checking-render-prop-2ie4h?file=/src/Modal.tsx) to be a `boolean`.

While this example is incredibly arbitrary, since the render props aren't exposed, if you were to lift the `isOpen` state to the `App` component, then it would still require checking that the `isOpen` prop type in the `Modal` component is a boolean (with either `PropTypes` or with your custom validator).

### Code

**App.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

const App = (): React.ReactElement => (
  <div className="app">
    <Modal>
      {({ isOpen, toggleModal }): React.ReactElement => (
        <>
          <h1 className="title">Hello!</h1>
          <p className="subtitle">
            The modal is currently {isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"}!
          </p>
          <p className="subtitle">There are two ways to close this modal:</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Click outside of this modal in the grey overlay area.</li>
            <li>Click the close button below.</li>
          </ul>
          <button
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger uk-button-small"
            onClick={toggleModal}
          >
            Close
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </Modal>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**Modal.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import withTypeCheck from "./withTypeCheck";

export type ChildrenProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  toggleModal: () => void;
};

export type ChildFunc = ({
  isOpen,
  toggleModal
}: ChildrenProps) => React.ReactElement;

export type ModalProps = {
  children: ChildFunc;
};

/**
 * Reuseable Modal component
 *
 * @param children - a render prop that accepts an object of `isOpen` and `toggleModal` props
 * @returns a ReactElement
 * @example <Modal>({ isOpen, toggleModal }) => (...)}</Modal>
 */
const Modal = ({ children }: ModalProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const [isOpen, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const wrapperRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const toggleModal = React.useCallback(() => {
    setVisible((prevState) => !prevState);
  }, []);

  const closeModal = React.useCallback(
    (e: Event): void => {
      if (
        isOpen &&
        wrapperRef.current &&
        !wrapperRef.current.contains(e.target as Node)
      ) {
        toggleModal();
      }
    },
    [isOpen, toggleModal]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", closeModal, { capture: true });

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", closeModal, { capture: true });
    };
  }, [closeModal]);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small"
        type="button"
        onClick={toggleModal}
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>
      {isOpen &&
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <>
            <div className="overlay" />
            <div className="window-container">
              <div className="modal-container">
                <div ref={wrapperRef} className="modal">
                  {withTypeCheck(children, { isOpen: "true", toggleModal })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>,
          document.body
        )}
    </>
  );
};

Modal.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Modal;
```

**withTypeCheck.ts** (you can swap out throwing the error with `console.error`, but throwing it will be more noticeable)

```
import type { ChildrenProps, ChildFunc } from "./Modal";

/**
 * Type checks a render prop function and its arguments.
 *
 * @param children - a render prop function
 * @args - an object of arugments containing `isOpen` and `toggleModal` props
 * @returns an error or ReactElement
 * @example withTypeCheck(fn, args);
 */
const withTypeCheck = (
  children: Function,
  args: ChildrenProps
): Error | ChildFunc => {
  try {
    const childrenType = typeof children;
    if (childrenType !== "function")
      throw String(
        `An invalid children prop was used inside the Modal component. Expected a function, but received ${childrenType}.`
      );

    const argTypes = typeof args;
    if (argTypes !== "object")
      throw String(
        `Invalid arguments were supplied to the children prop. Expected an object, but received ${argTypes}.`
      );

    const isOpenType = typeof args.isOpen;
    if (isOpenType !== "boolean")
      throw String(
        `An invalid 'isOpen' argument was supplied to the Modal's children prop. Expected a boolean, but received a ${isOpenType}.`
      );

    const toggleModalType = typeof args.toggleModal;
    if (toggleModalType !== "function")
      throw String(
        `An invalid 'toggleModalType' was argument supplied to the Modal's children prop. Expected a function, but received a ${toggleModalType}.`
      );

    return children(args);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default withTypeCheck;
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: This is helpful, but i am trying to have this capability at compile time. I know prop types are only for checking types at runtime, but vscode still generates types for them at compile time and uses that to provide intellisense. I understand the custom validator function at runtime, but was looking for some way to declare it at compile time, so that intellisense can work alright